# How to find out who references a given volume?

Tags: docker

I have a volume that isn't recognized as orphaned:

```
>docker volume ls -qf dangling=true
>docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               70cb...
```

I assume it's used by one of my containers, but how can I find out which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to ask a volume what containers belong to, but you can ask what volumes a container has a reference to. You can loop over each container and look for the volume in question. For example, this bash loop around the docker CLI should do the trick:

```
export volume=70cb
for container in $(docker ps -aq); 
    do docker inspect $container \
       | grep $volume \
       && echo $container matches;
    done
```

This, of course, is prone to false positives in the off chance than any of the `docker inspect` output arbitrarily matches the value you pass in for the volume, but it is a good starting point.